# My music is relooping but I am preventing it, how and why?

Tags: java

Here is my code from my main class.

```
static boolean music = true;
```

And here is my code from my Frame

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.InputStream;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class frmMainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  boolean Music = ProjetFinal.music;
  public frmMainMenu() {
    initComponents();
    while (Music == true) {
      try {
       InputStream test = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("musics/menu.wav");
       AudioStream Audio = new AudioStream(test);   
       AudioPlayer.player.start(Audio); 
       Music = false;
      } catch (Exception e){}
System.err.println("Exception occurred: ");
Music = false;        
}

}
```

It pritns out the "Exception occurred:" in my console but how do I fix it, I mean, I don't understand what the error is. It happens on startup of my program/frame.

Comment: Try adding a System.out.println() after the while loop. I am going to guess you are going to see that println() long before the music has stopped playing, because the audio is being played in a different thread.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is throwing an exception which you are blindly catching and not logging. After that it reloops because it hasn't had a chance to set Music to false yet.

This is just one of many reasons why you should never have an empty `catch` block.

```
catch (final Exception e) 
{ 
   System.err.println("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage()); 
}
finally { Music = false; }
```

Comment: Using `e.printStackTrace();` in my block should do fine to? If so, nothing pops up in the console.

Comment: Using catch `(Exception e){}
    System.err.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
    Music = false;        
} `  without the `e` because it gives me an error prints out the line in console.

Comment: The point is not in logging, the point is in doing something appropriate when an exception occurs. In your case it may make sense to log it or not. But it looks like it certainly makes sense to set `Music` to false.

Comment: So... I entered this and it still won't work but no JOption panes pop up and it still does the same thing, relooping the music. `catch (final Exception e) 
{ 
   System.err.println("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage()); 
}
finally { Music = false; }`

Comment: Add logging statements between each line of code in the `try` block to see what is executed, or attach a debugger and walk through the code line by line to see what's going wrong.